# Unknown circuit symbol ("10 NP")

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier

I'm trying to figure out what the following schematic symbol is:

[image: unknown circuit symbol]

I'm referring to the "10 NP" with the two vertical bars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a **10uF non-polarized electrolytic capacitor**.

Here's a similar ECG front-end circuit that uses the AD620 as an electrode amplifier (from [this site](http://fabrice.sincere.pagesperso-orange.fr/cm_electronique/projet_pic/cardiogramme/cardiogramme.htm), en Francais):

[image]

In that case, the designer used a 2,2uF film capacitor with a 2,2M resistor to form a 0.033 Hz high pass filter (\$ f_C = \frac {1}{2\pi RC})\$.

As has been pointed out, the symbol is not quite correct. Here are a couple suggested symbols for non-polarized (NP) capacitors (also BP bipolar capacitors, which some manufacturers distinguish)- from this site [here](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/Testing%20Electronic%20Components/TestingComponents.html).

[image]

Comment: if it's non polarized, it's strange that it shows a polarized style symbol. maybe their schematic capture program didn't have easily available non-polarized symbols..

Comment: Then why has he/she used a symbol of polarized capacitor?

Comment: @KyranF I'm agree with you

Comment: not only is there no units, but the symbol doesn't match the comment of "NP". Damn cryptic engineers!

Comment: @KyranF That's the probable explanation for the symbol (and the lack of a + sign).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany indeed. It's an electrode signal buffer so probably low frequency, so you think the 10uF in terms of "uF" units is most likely?

Comment: @KyranF For sure it is 10uF. There would be no need to specify NP if it was nF or pF, because it would not be an electrolytic capacitor in that case (and NP really is only used with electrolytics, and the symbol is electrolytic).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  indeed, the commonly accepted capacitor unit is uF (or on some supplier sites, which is extremely annoying, is pF)

Comment: Since there is no DC component at the instrumentation amplifier out, then it is a non-polarized cap to drive the next S&H stage.

Comment: @GRTech More precisely the InAmp has an **unpredictable** (and undesired) DC component, and it is blocked by the high-pass filter leaving the desired signal. Because the voltage could be positive or negative (and the next stage is ground-referenced), you need an NP cap.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany Right. I mean there is no AC component overrited in DC